# Drupal, in a content type display some text depending on the value of a date field

Tags: drupal-7, conditional-statements, field

I have a problem that puzzled me for quite a long time with the display of certain text depending on the value of a pair of date fields.
I have created a content type that includes two fields, a start date and an end date. I have also a third field titled "status" and I would like to make it display the values "in preparation", "in progress", "completed" depending on the value of the start/end dates.
Could you please guide me on how to do that?
I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use template_preprocess_field and alter your field based on $vars['element']['#field_name'].
Also there is an $vars['element']['#object'] object that holds the original entity.